# having different links to open multiple instance of jquery modal box on same page

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I'm using jquery modal box which is working fine with just one link on the page but after creating different url to open a different instance of the modal box, it stopped working.

I need to be able to create different url that should be able to open it's own instance of the jquery modal box with it unique content being fetched from the database and also being able to launch these modal boxes on the same page without jquery conflict.

Code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Animation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/js_css/jquery.ui.all.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.button.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.effect.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.effect-blind.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.effect-explode.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/js_css/demos.css">
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 1000
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "explode",
                duration: 1000
            }
        });

        $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the dialog for displaying information.</p>
</div>

<button id="opener">Open Dialog 1</button>

<br><br>

<button id="opener">Open Dialog 2</button>

<br><br>

<button id="opener">Open Dialog 3</button>

<br><br>

<a href="" id="opener">Open dialog 4 via this link</a>

<br><br>

<a href="" id="opener">Open dialog 5 via this link</a>


</body>
</html>
```

Would be pleased getting help with this.

Comment: don't use duplicate id's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[IDs must be unique.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute)**

Change the instances of `id="opener"` to `class="opener"` and change `$("#opener").click(...)` to `$(".opener").click(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8wtQa/)

**HTML Code**

```
<div class='my-container'>
    <button class="opener">Open Dialog 1</button>
    <div class="mydialog" title="Basic dialog 1">
    <p>My Dialog 1: Test data.</p>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class='my-container'>
    <button class="opener">Open Dialog 1</button>
    <div class="mydialog" title="Basic dialog 2">
    <p>My Dialog 2: Test information.</p>
</div>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$('.opener').on('click',function(){
    var mydivdialog = $(this).parent().children('.mydialog').first();
    console.log(mydivdialog);
    mydivdialog.dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 1000
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "explode",
                duration: 1000
            }
        });
    mydivdialog.dialog("open");
});
```

Note: As others have said, IDs must be unique. Use classes for multiple html elements as seen in my example.